# how to add setMajorIntervalLength in core plot?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a data like that

```
(@"jan", @"feb", @"mar", @"apr", @"may", @"jun", @"jul", @"aug", @"sep", @"oct", @"nov", @"dec")
```

I need to add these below data into **x-axis** with interval 2.

```
`( @"jan", @"mar", @"may", , @"jul", @"sep", @"nov")`
```

How can I achieve this one in core plot **Line chart**.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

```
`NSMutableArray *monthLabelset = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *monthsDataset = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *months = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"jan",@"feb",@"mar",@"apr",@"may",@"jun",@"jul",@"aug",@"sep",@"oct",@"nov",@"dec", nil];

    for (int i = 0; i<months.count; i++)
    {
        CPTAxisLabel *monthsLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc]initWithText:[months objectAtIndex:i] textStyle:xAxis.labelTextStyle];
        monthsLabel.tickLocation  = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
        monthsLabel.offset        =  3.0;
        NSString *month = [months objectAtIndex:i];
        if (monthsLabel)
        {
            if(i%2 == 0)
            {
                [monthLabelset addObject:monthsLabel];
                [monthsDataset addObject:month];
            }

        }


    }

    NSMutableSet *monthLabels = [[NSMutableSet alloc]initWithArray:monthLabelset];
    NSMutableSet *monthsData  = [[NSMutableSet alloc]initWithArray:monthsDataset];
    xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    xAxis.axisLabels = monthLabels;
    xAxis.majorTickLocations = monthsData;

        plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] length:[NSNumber numberWithInt:11]];
        plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(yAxisMin)] length:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(yAxisMax - yAxisMin)]];
        [xAxis setMajorIntervalLength:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
        [yAxis setMajorIntervalLength:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
        [yAxis setLabelFormatter:axisFormatter];

        CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
        CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
        [xRange expandRangeByFactor:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.06]];
        [yRange expandRangeByFactor:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.06]];
        plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
        plotSpace.yRange = yRange;
`
```

i added below code

```
    if(i%2 == 0)
    {
        [monthLabelset addObject:monthsLabel];
        [monthsDataset addObject:month];
    }
```